# Creating a URL in the page layout based on page field

Tags: page-layout

I have a contact email address in my page layout. I want to make that link clickable, but  doesn't work in the href tag. What is the best way to get this to work in the page layout? Do I need to use jquery for this, we are trying to avoid that but if its my only option I guess Ill need to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

if I'm not wrong you can try to use SPContext.Current.Item in the page layout like this

```
<a href='<%= SPContext.Current.Item["filedName"] ?? "/" %>'>Link</a>
```

Comment: I cant use code blocks in the page layout, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Can you store your data as a string with tag "a" in you field and use this line of code `<SharePoint:FieldValue id="someid" FieldName="FieldName" runat="server"/>`?

Comment: nope tried that too, its looking like Ill need to use jquery

Comment: have you tried to use Hyperlink field type to store data? and FieldValue control?

Comment: I found [this post](http://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/how-to-pull-a-custom-column-into-a-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2010/). In this post the link is built for Lookup field. I think that it should work for your field too.

Comment: I think that post will work with a little tweaking on my end. Thanks for finding it.